# Is there any way to determine how long it took for the DAO attacker to deploy the attack?

Tags: ether, the-dao, dao

Yeah, we heard that the DAO has been attacked. I am so curious about how long it took for the attacker to perform the whole transactions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first attack took place in transaction [0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b) that occurred in block [1718497](http://etherscan.io/block/1718497) mined 9 hrs 15 mins ago (6/17/2016 3:34:48 AM).

The attack seems to have stopped with the last transaction [0xa348da60799bff3ca804b3e49c96edebea44c5728a97f64bec3e21056d42f6e3](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xa348da60799bff3ca804b3e49c96edebea44c5728a97f64bec3e21056d42f6e3) that occurred in block [1720245](http://etherscan.io/block/1720245) mined 1 hr 51 mins ago (6/17/2016 11:00:23 AM).

Here is the contract address [0x304a554a310C7e546dfe434669C62820b7D83490](http://etherscan.io/address/0x304a554a310C7e546dfe434669C62820b7D83490#internaltx) that was receiving the hacked ethers.

And here is the list of the [27996](http://etherscan.io/txsInternal?a=0x304a554a310C7e546dfe434669C62820b7D83490) internal transactions to transfer the ethers.

The whole attack took 7 hours 24 minutes.

---

### Some Other Statistics

- 3,641,694.241898506 Ether ($59,578,117.80) was moved to the account [0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490](http://etherscan.io/address/0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490).
- 7,928,991.62 Ether ($130,590,492.12) is remaining in [The DAO](http://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO), with an additional 344,907.73 Ether ($5,680,630.44) in the extraBalances account.
- 30.56% of ETH from The DAO was hacked. Calculation: 3,641,694.241898506 / (3,641,694.241898506 + 7,928,991.62 + 344,907.73).
- The current total token supply is 1,155,955,830.9 The DAO ($138,714,699.71).
- If the hardfork described in [CRITICAL UPDATE Re: DAO Vulnerability](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/17/critical-update-re-dao-vulnerability/) is accepted by consensus, The DAO is dissolved, and the ETH returned to The DAO token holders, each 100 DAO tokens would receive 1.03 ETH (without taking into account the token holders who paid > 1 ETH = 100 DAO). Calculation: (3,641,694.241898506 + 7,928,991.62 + 344,907.73) / 1,155,955,830.9 = 0.010308001 .

  But according to [Thoughts on The DAO Hack](http://hackingdistributed.com/2016/06/17/thoughts-on-the-dao-hack/), funds in the extraBalances is not accessible, so the number is more 1.00096263 ETH = 100 DAO. Calculation: (3,641,694.241898506 + 7,928,991.62) / 1,155,955,830.9 = 0.0100096263 .
- And if the hardfork described in [CRITICAL UPDATE Re: DAO Vulnerability](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/17/critical-update-re-dao-vulnerability/) is rejected by consensus, The DAO token have 0.7157625861 ETH backing each 100 DAO tokens. Calculation: (7,928,991.62 + 344,907.73) / 1,155,955,830.9 = 0.7157625861 .

  And if funds in the extraBalances is not accessible, DAO tokens have 0.68592514 ETH backing each 100 DAO tokens. Calculation: 7,928,991.62 / 1,155,955,830.9 = 0.0068592514
  .