# Which split proposal was used to mount the recursive call vulnerability attack on The DAO?

Tags: security, the-dao, attacks

I'm assuming that a split proposal was used to mount the recursive call vulnerability attack on The DAO.

Which of the splits below was used to mount this attack?

Here are the current list of splits:

```
   Prop Status                Yea             Nay Recipient                                  Description                             
------- --------- --------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
      1 Expired         967598.22      4276278.60 0x13680fa2a60fd551894199f009cca20fb63a3e31                                         
      4 Expired           5279.34      4322941.58 0x3d5507b53d1613d8491a606ecf5c9268301095dd split                                   
      6 Expired              1.99       175453.91 0xbeb0b93c01297146782a5581370489a36b24deca Original intent, non-interventionist cur
      7 Expired         118006.68      3967413.62 0xe82d5b10ad98d34df448b07a5a62c1affbef758f Leave me alone                          
      8 Expired         199999.99      3931880.95 0xa72ded5c1122312d9f4ed66bf4a396139eadaf56                                         
      9 Expired        2659899.77      3911880.49 0x228d29ea776cb17ca0db0538562ecaacdc0a9e46                                         
     10 Expired          15746.04      3933147.83 0x374139a05ac55917badd3f934f1b93f5c8623ded                                         
     12 Expired           5281.35      3945155.27 0xcdc00dd1459e293c9c81880a2b3c4e5396a8ef7b �� cdc00 split proposal ��      
     13 Expired          46039.25      3926435.27 0xf8f9fc62a19c87c657a06febd184f068c0fc9cae arbitrage ftw                           
     14 Expired          51751.22      3873726.70 0x1502447aadf5979e7a842709cd6c4f60afb0a281                                         
     16 Expired         130199.49      3892661.67 0x7c81d252d9d1295058cd3620835f37e0eedd8840 Split 0x7C8                             
     18 Expired           2200.20      3913649.01 0x13680fa2a60fd551894199f009cca20fb63a3e31                                         
     19 Expired        1686495.65      3906900.95 0xf398c9b8107dccc697546969fb2d5956762b60fb split-ID-x8nj2z                         
     20 Expired           1000.00      3906620.95 0xe7535ddfcbefe5c318d271476d068d5f7cf77290                                         
     21 Expired              0.00      3866620.95 0xe7535ddfcbefe5c318d271476d068d5f7cf77290                                         
     22 Expired         239999.99      3894155.12 0x95a61f934d66580dd410a7369f9c5b8e228d2ff3                                         
     23 Expired           9999.85      3885353.61 0x357d083321319cc1a8ebad90ba1db06c8698eef6 sploot                                  
     24 Expired             10.00      3885353.61 0x3065a8444787f076bff10e5df3ec66606e3c8b68 WL split                                
     25 Expired         100000.00      3885353.61 0x1873f651ecf56d27c01d8d17a1bf06a9acf8830b 0x187 canonball                         
     26 Expired          10000.00      3885353.61 0x2b15c5211bda6a867c582080536f6c61766aa5af 0x2b15 DAO Split                        
     27 Expired           4117.33      3881046.67 0xa7c605a1aacb641d873c82f9b2715e87339dfd48 n0k0 split                              
     28 Expired          22737.70      3885353.61 0xb18e6467db64686dfed14c7368ca59e5019c95c8 0xB18e split                            
     29 Expired        1275842.51        46973.61 0xd68ba7734753e2ee54103116323aba2d94c78dc5                                         
     30 Expired          24653.70        44306.95 0x479abf2da4d58716fd973a0d13a75f530150260a                                         
     31 Expired           7318.67        44306.95 0xf8c3879ee8dde81f074abca79b2270eab9942ec1 my_pitui                                
     32 Expired          18007.67        44306.95 0xb42da5b3701a0592e5aa0aebc0c20711bd49fb46 0xB42 private split                     
     33 Expired           7312.66        44306.95 0xcf69ab35bb6a87a68ce83571a174eef4f998baa7                                         
     34 Expired          26685.38        45306.95 0xfdf97eaa34a883647fac329926b1747e9ef601c6 arbitrageservice 0.00 - test            
     35 Expired            331.23        45306.95 0xaf496a1083a3a7c7edb831f2e9a31eb065f5a228 E's Castle Rock                         
     36 Expired              9.00        45306.95 0xaf496a1083a3a7c7edb831f2e9a31eb065f5a228 Galt's Gulch                            
     37 Expired           7676.17        44306.95 0x98dac39fdcc5c9a8dfc6f63898b62704806851b4 0x98dac split                           
     38 Open              4563.99         4306.95 0x3822e5ff792e75817b89f5bbb405fc4a9d1a0552 The Ilium Works                         
     39 Expired         212183.45      3904410.23 0xf4c0eef475ab35625ac223394f9c410ccb577747 GFX, others please don't vote           
     41 Expired              0.19      3888583.17 0xfaed3f06255794bf3f83d7ab08d4554d5d218b41                                         
     42 Expired          54977.28      3896914.31 0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413                                         
     44 Expired          25000.00      3910120.72 0x5a422fb07fc9270f5b310fc61f85b8e779cb29a2 Hotdog cheap plot gongzho dao           
     45 Expired             99.99      3844276.22 0x5824a7486ea2ec17749f936c7b89faa4972f8eb1                                         
     46 Expired             99.99      3844276.22 0x5824a7486ea2ec17749f936c7b89faa4972f8eb1                                         
     47 Expired             99.99      3844276.22 0x5824a7486ea2ec17749f936c7b89faa4972f8eb1                                         
     48 Expired             99.99      3844276.22 0x5824a7486ea2ec17749f936c7b89faa4972f8eb1                                         
     49 Expired            737.68      3844276.22 0x5824a7486ea2ec17749f936c7b89faa4972f8eb1                                         
     50 Expired              0.00      3844276.22 0x0ee82c5e35cbcf9e1271808f0386b930ee8ae8a2 m split                                 
     52 Expired            350.00      3844526.22 0x56ae819a1bc418121a6e8428b5884f7604152322 test split 1337                         
     53 Expired           1000.00      3847136.35 0x4853143d0f5524df67a0a5bdd2fb63c76c7693f6 arbitrage ftw 2                         
     54 Expired            200.00      3838630.00 0x0f935781046701897c9e0d9876fb5c82d89d53be split me baby one more time             
     55 Expired         477555.42      3838380.00 0xf2a83b593162d77c62337a02668be1ee088cb55d 0xF2a83 Split                           
     56 Expired            500.00      3858630.46 0x55d1554b08a5311c5c0a0b6464162192f9d2f884 Baby Split                              
     57 Expired              1.99      3838380.00 0x065f074f1e93a215a9a05b2c92059ca44a4827eb split-0x065f                            
     58 Expired            560.00      3838630.00 0xc4dc238f4ff143480f64456e0c4837e1c802934e this is rickdiculous!                   
     59 Expired              0.00      3838630.00 0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a lonely, so lonely                       
     60 Expired             10.00            0.00 0x65c407ffea9fcff194fe9d3335d2b78416226056 0x65split                               
     61 Expired            500.00          250.00 0x42b8a09e46e6e367ed0135d3cd7fbdce777e0873 banana split                            
     62 Expired         115105.50          250.00 0x4e0494181464ce213089eb86b8195ed135eb4d48 0x4E04 split proposal                   
     63 Expired          55938.40          250.00 0x46664c1e2ddd896a3e0c2b3d502842f261b9e62f Toni split                              
     64 Expired        3069669.68          250.00 0x547389052a8dc86365c46641b5184956ec22749d 0x54738 Split                           
     65 Expired            500.00          250.00 0x208e4a03118380b4f63cf056ecbfe0a241a41b46 0x28e 432 split                         
     66 Expired         100000.00          250.00 0x9a9d6a470fc8034085ee8e509623e2f742da6625 THE DAO SHOWS THAT VAROUFAKIS HAS NO VIS
     67 Expired             10.00          250.00 0x3065a8444787f076bff10e5df3ec66606e3c8b68 WL split again                          
     68 Expired              0.00          250.00 0x4b595e2328b73a7f4e4cb65b506a74d836bbd7f9                                         
     69 Expired       11765917.31            0.00 0x55d1554b08a5311c5c0a0b6464162192f9d2f884 Congo Split                             
     70 Expired       43109582.83          250.00 0x55d1554b08a5311c5c0a0b6464162192f9d2f884 Congo Split                             
     71 Expired        6591642.51          250.00 0xc1aba55035310a703ee450142eb31961a2723006 beer split                              
     72 Expired        3546051.15          250.00 0x3c111dde8bbe5270b55f85e7c377c8fe4ee26242 FUN-SPLT-42                             
     73 Open                21.99            0.00 0xa003e4b91180d3e06a03f1916fe94eb4c350850e                                         
     74 Open               131.58            0.00 0x1bc31e2e4f1bcc0a7dd9d849dfc57e66e59896ab                                         
     75 Open                21.99            0.00 0x98e27ba4f77f2b4149402c0fd7b92921b47ac8f1 TestSplitT                              
     76 Open               101.90            0.00 0x7727b2afc5a6816452a455e65a6a7dd01d03af4b Split Proposal - C                      
     77 Open              3999.89            0.00 0xe52435be3f079a6185f62766cbac3c0bdfaea5b4                                         
     78 Open             33323.56            0.00 0x5494167cc3404fcc4e2435c124d0f661a8f45861 Northern split                          
     79 Open             20000.00            0.00 0x0449d907531168fbe26afc381a4ae005e31bbe75 SplitxProposal Are there stalkers?      
     80 Open                 0.00            0.00 0xc4dc238f4ff143480f64456e0c4837e1c802934e Split 0xc4D                             
     81 Open             32000.00            0.00 0x83444307da515dc6646ae0201c718d783897d772 blaa blaa blaa                          
     83 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x81fff0f75c6cb65bc9799922c18b27d211131079 Split-Zg7vm2                            
     85 Open              5010.00            0.00 0x51476eb4696e33b412091f09b5463e83598b555e EpSplit                                 
     86 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x862656d0db96c32c7cc551e1e22780c394c9e24e Split. Please don't stalk. Bye.         
     87 Open                 0.00            0.00 0xffbf6b9f8d575765f430392b57a29ddf92c365a0 Split ffbf                              
     88 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x7b49fe515e027f80cc93a9d6db6e3c5aaca91917                                         
     89 Open            110000.00            0.00 0x1873f651ecf56d27c01d8d17a1bf06a9acf8830b NEW SOLOSPLIT PROPOSAL AGAIN BECAUSE THE
     90 Open                 0.00            0.00 0xf2a83b593162d77c62337a02668be1ee088cb55d                                         
     91 Open                17.06            0.00 0x522b59b92a4566440ae3ef8e3426fbfaa2f37a9b schplitter                              
     92 Open              8177.04            0.00 0x14c81f47cda966e90c5ff7fc1a3f81012dd8b721 moose1                                  
     93 Open               200.00            0.00 0xef0b9496aaf4245db417ba821818340f6213ecd1 06/14-1465895020                        
     94 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x55d1554b08a5311c5c0a0b6464162192f9d2f884 Last hurrah                             
     95 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x55d1554b08a5311c5c0a0b6464162192f9d2f884 Hammer Split                            
     96 Open              3000.00            0.00 0x996114abfffe481c05c5341098b284679f158d53 0x99611 split                           
     97 Open            100000.00            0.00 0x5236a1870aee21aa83a55c534127b43a775d216f T A X A T I O N    I S    T H E F T     
     98 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x522b59b92a4566440ae3ef8e3426fbfaa2f37a9b                                         
     99 Open             14000.80            0.00 0x8d184669301640a42652e9b436843a3fa4998370 moose2                                  
    100 Open                 1.00            0.00 0x8fdb7441bd9263499af346135153a737aa9b3fbb                                         
    101 Open              1009.98            0.00 0x5fbea6b04d5824c73a89cb8348d66492e0e4b7bf split909090                             
    102 Open                 0.00            0.00 0xd68ba7734753e2ee54103116323aba2d94c78dc5                                         
    103 Open             46732.67            0.00 0xaa09688e89371fee6dcda9dd7a995737e2a3a196 squids split proposal                   
    104 Open                10.00            0.00 0x8bebbfbc64a23a31fa3a003c1883b0ef26514400 0x8beb split                            
    105 Open             80258.05            0.00 0xbb5c7fccc433fb92d04064816cbee74070f9ec90 Split 0xBB5                             
    106 Open              5000.00            0.00 0x8c99b1fab831dae42fa8acd4f3a05a19f443f559                                         
    107 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x522163712cadf19b64d13b0cb0f07024081d23cb Split 0xbeef                            
    108 Open             38400.92            0.00 0x465423cb836d2809811c9c5309a3c7e4d53e3d20 0x4654 Split                            
    109 Open              8000.00            0.00 0xaf8bd1432b1baf546ae1751769d31a633841c605                                         
    110 Open               689.12            0.00 0x64d4c6a676b0314d747847d2314634aa71126a09                                         
    111 Open               121.99            0.00 0xffff16f80329cd2110c1dea6715a678fc826b43b split prop 0xffff16f                    
    112 Open              5231.99            0.00 0xb9c13e25933c54b68ed425a862272db940386bee refundsplit                             
    113 Open             66531.90            0.00 0xf49efc9b25bed7694dc1cbfd119dcef5862c25bd                                         
    114 Open              6034.58            0.00 0x1ea0517703749db2619d54ccd8de0b53494008ed AngSplit                                
    115 Open                22.00            0.00 0xe3cbc85806a5407ed22e087e9a4ee1c8f934b82b 0xe3Cb Split                            
    116 Open                22.00            0.00 0x2c4c5cf7aedbe989a07acd7d071053ecd331c74c 0x2C4c Split                            
    117 Open                22.00            0.00 0x129344ed0f059580bf667a27bd15a5dea0b751d6 0x1293 Split                            
    118 Open                22.00            0.00 0x899d6a07c90ad5eb406ba2165ae0d55415a8e752 0x899d Split                            
    119 Open                22.00            0.00 0xb6bfe6ae7d164cfcd4622de6e87fb55a54e7220e 0xB6bF Split                            
    120 Open             29341.99            0.00 0x907b7be980917cdda0346bd747f026393e794df7 0xFEFE Split Proposal                   
    121 Open              6021.99            0.00 0x94b6c4e1af692c88fb8c9f69fa961098ce8fab67 split prop 0x94b6c4                     
    122 Open                21.99            0.00 0x81d0fae35a74c5105c4332f6ede87fd27344f5c1 0x81d split                             
    123 Open                21.99            0.00 0xa852246e4ac2da710afa72aa1a60f03620d1978a 123 split                               
    124 Open             11021.99            0.00 0x131ba80e1ae0d9a9a3b905193ed76122acf36541                                         
    125 Open              1021.99            0.00 0x77d0967ffddbad3aba301837208392573da29299 BloomSplit                              
    126 Open             13049.65            0.00 0xbaed532ec78c440abb51ad325b1593ef72c03bf3 0xbAED split proposal                   
    127 Open             18221.83            0.00 0x8d08aa327c884af528deac25dd5df7ba74bf7f69 life is opinion                         
    128 Open                21.99            0.00 0x4ee4723e0c54e0aa4fee0d3d24c0fca1f7ac4178 lickety-split                           
    129 Open              8021.99            0.00 0x6b890f9aecbbc163ccb6e06f19afeb5516aefc71                                         
    130 Open             13021.99            0.00 0xcc9fa6eb6ab4279841f93f6945b8d0ffa4e534a8                                         
    131 Open                21.99            0.00 0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413                                         
    132 Open            415321.99            0.00 0x13d8c756f609b6a9f0077a6d149f0e817b9a9ab5 JOY                                     
    133 Open                21.99            0.00 0x00ff1d79e83997b205e7f0284f6f0502d75d979a split                                   
    134 Open                21.99            0.00 0x525abf0142ea4102982eefd5c57f7500c307e3f6 sp                                      
    135 Open                21.99            0.00 0x525abf0142ea4102982eefd5c57f7500c307e3f6 sp2                                     
    136 Open                21.99            0.00 0x53337dbed2981c8c9c2d73c865317951c4b1f4c6                                         
    137 Open                21.99            0.00 0x525abf0142ea4102982eefd5c57f7500c307e3f6 sp3                                     
    138 Open            102642.14            0.00 0x802bde4e1977e1f7bfc51d49b8896fd40e3606a1 F$CK, SH!T P!SS                         
    139 Open             25021.99            0.00 0xfd589b0573e12f1266155b02fd6636081e9e03dc split proposal 6581                     
    140 Open           2299831.49            0.00 0x81c636277383b06b9cc3983089c86441deedfab5 Bye bye DAO                             
    141 Open                21.99            0.00 0x5f633807a48c326123712ec5b492219029adde98                                         
    142 Open             10081.99            0.00 0xfa8ede0792b8a4f0d5299d76730244ba76b4ab0b splitt                                  
    143 Open              9921.99            0.00 0x92bcabf8179b00b1c18c8b1fb31fc6fb7caccec0 0x92BCab split proposal                 
    144 Open                21.99            0.00 0x5f633807a48c326123712ec5b492219029adde98                                         
    145 Open            615021.99            0.00 0x45d803c38f1bf8ca9cf2154f66a3e4ee4ad1a44c                                         
    146 Open             30000.00            0.00 0x00e8ac9aff4bd73e68bca39e76cdf15ff7f592c4                                         
    147 Open             14000.00            0.00 0xd60651e393783423e5cc1bc5f889e44ef7ea243e                                         
    148 Open                 0.00            0.00 0xeda3c50ee6af463cdf2b0b1bbf859ca56fb92d9b gzfs split                              
    149 Open             33000.00            0.00 0xe7aa7aeab52b8479e2c04a5af79ac0862265ba62 VM Split                                
    150 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x48c163de076cd3ac5fdc493c2b62cf3cb554b6c1                                         
    151 Open           2001200.00            0.00 0x48c163de076cd3ac5fdc493c2b62cf3cb554b6c1 propsp_1                                
    152 Open             42500.00            0.00 0x3942d7a7a71548d55ae284dae89e83326e140578 PH - Split                              
    153 Open           1000100.00            0.00 0x3cd0c53aa2455a4c740add11ecd8bfea0aae141b splt2                                   
    154 Open           1000150.00            0.00 0xd96ca3ca549669e3c4b1dec0d5d57dfcef9b27bd splt                                    
    155 Open            500500.00            0.00 0x412b8ceecc499dea1a355f8de2ad7d3cf27f9af8 spl                                     
    156 Open            101100.00            0.00 0x42484e5c43c75f6df8264ccff8a4b190c4f0f148 sp                                      
    157 Open             10658.95            0.00 0x5d6d5bea4f20bd7130917ef8ef6902ded28f536e sppl                                    
    158 Open                21.99            0.00 0xdf44dc408b085f9344d78fecca4981e7df474160 ethoutasap                              
    159 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x6fc4d393bcebc69dbc8a6877e098babd19504e3b 0x6FC4 split proposal                   
    160 Open                31.72            0.00 0x082ab210f44f3e644cd2ea76c516a7cfa9b67555 Ethereum-kaufen.de Tutorial             
    161 Open             15100.00            0.00 0x1eb53a7bcdf2f8eceb50468005b5bf6f01ba593b Split                                   
    162 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x8e08b284f1383f76bafbe14aab4dc859f63640ab split0x8e                               
    163 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x8e08b284f1383f76bafbe14aab4dc859f63640ab                                         
    164 Open               400.00            0.00 0x6adc4e3d436886ca1851dc14fb773365eb60ab63 Split                                   
    165 Open                 0.00            0.00 0x8527e7947c0cce9a5ddee6d566c69497d2e7be0b narf                                    
    166 Open             60000.00            0.00 0xb394730f0f9d16567e5ef7e17434f5c12bc7ea1e 0xb394730f0f Split. Do not vote yes or t
    167 Open               100.00            0.00 0x9192ca96de0b90f2a67a2d81f4a1325cfa3cc685 MT-Dao Split                            
    168 Open                 0.00            0.00 0xe845e387c4cbdf982280f6aa01c40e4be958ddb2 K                                       
------- --------- --------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
Closed                       0.00            0.00 Yeas 0.00% of the original supply
Expired               76772594.40    152768545.58 Yeas 6.55% of the original supply
Open                   8979373.55         4306.95 Yeas 0.77% of the original supply
Total                 85751967.95    152772852.53 Yeas 7.31% of the original supply
Supply  Current     1155588304.96                 Reduction from original supply of 16930766.51 or 1.44%
Supply  Original    1172519071.47
------- --------- --------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
Notes: Nay votes don't affect split votes
Generated by theDAOVoter at Sat Jun 18 13:18:41 2016
```

Some further information:

- The first transaction used to mount the attack was [0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b) as listed in [Is there any way to determine how long it took for the DAO attacker to deploy the attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6177/1268)
- Here is a .zip of the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` of the first of the attacker's transaction - [TheDAORecursiveCallAttack-FirstTransactionDebug.txt.zip](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAORecursiveCallAttack/raw/master/TheDAORecursiveCallAttack-FirstTransactionDebug.txt.zip).

Comment: See this https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-rise-of-the-dark-dao-72b21a2212e3#.nb7tlkvp0 seems to have a good research

Comment: Hi `@Ismael`, I suspected proposal #59 as the second parameter in the first transaction listed in [Which accounts are involved in mounting the recursive call vulnerability attacks on The DAO?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6224/which-accounts-are-involved-in-mounting-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attacks) was `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003b` = 59 but was not sure as there was 0 Yes votes on this proposal. Please add your link as an answer with #59 and I'll accept your answer (+flesh it out a bit or the moderators will flag is a not-an-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The rise of the Dark DAO](https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-rise-of-the-dark-dao-72b21a2212e3) for a good research about the bug.

In it Johannes Pfeffer states:

> - The malicious proposal from which the attack was launched: #59, aka “lonely, so lonely”, 2016–06–08 05:38:01 UTC, before the recursion call [bug](http://vessenes.com/more-ethereum-attacks-race-to-empty-is-the-real-deal/) [went public](https://blog.slock.it/no-dao-funds-at-risk-following-the-ethereum-smart-contract-recursive-call-bug-discovery-29f482d348b) on 2016–06–10

**EDIT 19/06/2016**

From the article [The attack story](https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-attack-story-38f4789b3c3b#.k1jlhcyud) by Johannes Pfeffer (with help from `@mKoeppelmann` and `@tayvano`):

[image]