# Which accounts are involved in mounting the recursive call vulnerability attacks on The DAO?

Tags: security, the-dao, attacks

The first transaction [0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b) was initiated from account [0x969837498944ae1dc0dcac2d0c65634c88729b2d](http://etherscan.io/address/0x969837498944ae1dc0dcac2d0c65634c88729b2d) to the contract at [0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89](http://etherscan.io/address/0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89).

The (formatted) payload of the first transaction was:

```
0xc4463c80
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003b
000000000000000000000000b656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a
000000000000000000000000f835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009
000000000000000000000000f35e2cc8e6523d683ed44870f5b7cc785051a77d
```

There seems to be some accounts in the payload that are:

- Account [0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a](http://etherscan.io/address/0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a)
- Contract [0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4](http://etherscan.io/address/0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4#code)
- Account [0xf35e2cc8e6523d683ed44870f5b7cc785051a77d](http://etherscan.io/address/0xf35e2cc8e6523d683ed44870f5b7cc785051a77d).

The destination contract for the hacked ethers is [0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490](http://etherscan.io/address/0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490) currently holding  3,641,694.241898506 Ether ($52,403,980.14).

In particular, which accounts used in the attack are under control of the attacker?

Some further information:

- The first transaction used to mount the attack was [0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b) as listed in [Is there any way to determine how long it took for the DAO attacker to deploy the attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6177/1268)
- Here is a .zip of the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` of the first of the attacker's transaction - [TheDAORecursiveCallAttack-FirstTransactionDebug.txt.zip](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAORecursiveCallAttack/raw/master/TheDAORecursiveCallAttack-FirstTransactionDebug.txt.zip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in `@Ismael`'s comment in [Which split proposal was used to mount the recursive call vulnerability attack on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6223/which-split-proposal-was-used-to-mount-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attack-o), there is some nice analysis in progress at [The rise of the Dark DAO](https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-rise-of-the-dark-dao-72b21a2212e3#.1h3psomio).

From the article, the following accounts may be involved:

Useful information

> Creator of the malicious DAO: [0x4a574510c7014e4ae985403536074abe582adfc8](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4a574510c7014e4ae985403536074abe582adfc8)
>
> [Start of the drain](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ec3f2488a93839524add10ea229e773f6bc891b4eb4794c3337d4495263790b): 2016–06–17 03:34:48 UTC, block 1718497
>
> The malicious child DAO aka “The Dark DAO”:[0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490](http://etherscan.io/address/0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490)
>
> Malicious token holders aka “Dark token holders”.
>
> These are the accounts that control the malicious DAO:
>
> - [0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89](http://etherscan.io/address/0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89)
> - [0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4](http://etherscan.io/address/0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4)
>
> Curator of the malicious DAO and creator of the malicious proposal:
>
> - [0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a](http://etherscan.io/address/0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a)
>
> The malicious proposal from which the attack was launched:
>
> #59, aka “lonely, so lonely”, 2016–06–08 05:38:01 UTC, before the recursion call bug went public on 2016–06–10
>
> Voted Yes:
>
> - [0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4](http://etherscan.io/address/0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4)
> - [0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89](http://etherscan.io/address/0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89)
>
> Voted No:
>
> - [0xca8e11c876180c9f2115fa61fe2a1a3a6f66ebaf](http://0xca8e11c876180c9f2115fa61fe2a1a3a6f66ebaf/)
> - [0x347c28ef5487b37a8e03040653a739f19b986b2d](http://etherscan.io/address/0x347c28ef5487b37a8e03040653a739f19b986b2d)
>
> Recipient as stated in the malicious proposal:
>
> - [0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a](http://etherscan.io/address/0xb656b2a9c3b2416437a811e07466ca712f5a5b5a)

**EDIT 19/06/2016**

To two attacking accounts [0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89](http://etherscan.io/address/0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89) and [0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4](http://etherscan.io/address/0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4) have multiple transfers of 25,805.6141471 DAO tokens, with the final destination account of [0xca04d260356d19f0d7255041542c9cbc866f2cb3](http://etherscan.io/address/0xca04d260356d19f0d7255041542c9cbc866f2cb3).

**EDIT 19/06/2016**

From the article [The attack story](https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-attack-story-38f4789b3c3b#.k1jlhcyud) by Johannes Pfeffer (with help from `@mKoeppelmann` and `@tayvano`):

[image]