# When will the Baddies have access to the hacked funds on the Ethereum Classic chain?

Tags: the-dao, attacks, hardforks, ethereum-classic, balances

The Baddies drained 3641694.241898506992612606 ETH via The DAO's child DAO #59.

When will the Baddies have access to the hacked funds on the Ethereum Classic chain?

See also:

- [Which split proposal was used to mount the recursive call vulnerability attack on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6223/which-split-proposal-was-used-to-mount-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attack-o)
- [How many ethers have been drained through the recursive call attacks on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/how-many-ethers-have-been-drained-through-the-recursive-call-attacks-on-the-dao)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Baddies joined into the Split Proposal #59 where they were not the curator. From this split, the Baddies created a number of split proposals where the Split Proposal #59.10 was used to split out the attacked funds into a split where the attacker was the curator. The Baddies have now created the Non-Split Proposals #59.10.1 and #59.10.2 where the funds can be withdrawn into the account **[0xc362ef3150969f89a22b95521c1a8683e3e864f1](https://gastracker.io/addr/0xc362ef3150969f89a22b95521c1a8683e3e864f1)** on the Classic chain.

Non-Split Proposal #59.10.1 can be executed from **Mon, 05 Sep 2016 21:56:22 GMT** and Non-Split Proposal #59.10.2 can be executed from **Mon, 05 Sep 2016 22:02:35 GMT**.

Here is a screenshot showing the difference in the attacker's Split Proposal #59 between [theDAOETCDrains_20160807_1255GMT.txt](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOETCDrains/blob/master/theDAOETCDrains_20160807_1255GMT.txt) and the latest generated report **[theDAOETCDrains_20160828_230144GMT.txt](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOETCDrains/blob/master/theDAOETCDrains_20160828_230144GMT.txt)**.

[image]

---

### UPDATE 22:13 Sep 5 2016 UTC

The hacker has just withdrawn their booty from The DAO on the ETC chain.

See https://gastracker.io/addr/0xc362ef3150969f89a22b95521c1a8683e3e864f1. The booty was then moved immediately to https://gastracker.io/addr/0x5e8f0e63e7614c47079a41ad4c37be7def06df5a with 1,000 ETC donated to the (now tainted) [Ethereum Classic developer fund](https://gastracker.io/addr/0xe9a7e26bf5c05fe3bae272d4c940bd7158611ce9).

Follow the live update at [The Hacker Has Just Withdrawn Their Booty From The DAO On The ETC Chain](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/51bwgd/the_hacker_has_just_withdrawn_their_booty_from/).

---

Further data and the [script to extract the data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOETCDrains/master/theDAOETCDrains) can be found at [github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOETCDrains](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOETCDrains), including the list of all the split proposals - summary shown below:

#### Summary Page 1

[image]

#### Summary Page 2

[image]