# Reentrant attack number on 17 June 2016

Tags: reentrant-attacks, call-depth-attacks

This post [What was the second vulnerability used in The DAO attack on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/what-was-the-second-vulnerability-used-in-the-dao-attack-on-17-june-2016) say :

> And from the Q&A [...], each of the transactions (the first and second 
>   at least from my manual counting) called splitDAO(...) 29 
>   times. But the 29 x splitDAO(...) calls were repeatedly called, creating > 27996 internal transactions, 13996 were non-zero internal transfers. 
>   Calculation: 13996 transactions x 258.05656476 ETH = 3,611,759.68038 
>   ethers, which is approximately the 3,641,694.241898506 Ether 
>   ($59,578,117.80) was moved to the account 
>   0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490.

But isn't the call depth size max size of Ethereum's call stack capped at 1024 ?
Most blog posts says this recursive can only be done ~ 30 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in [What was the second vulnerability used in The DAO attack on 17 June 2016?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/what-was-the-second-vulnerability-used-in-the-dao-attack-on-17-june-2016) .

What the attacker did was to transfer their tokens from account to account so they could repeatedly call the SplitDAO recursively 29 x something like:

```
for (i = 1 to 482) {
    call wallet default function () // which performed the following:
        // transfer tokens to another account
        // call splitDAO(...) with recursion to the depth of 29x.
}
```

From the link above:

> It's not so much a vulnerability, but the attack cleverly transferred its DAO tokens between 2 accounts, by using function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount).
>
> So the fallback function of the attacking contract looks like:
>
> ```
> function() {
>   transfer DAO tokens to other attacking contract
>   invoke splitDAO
> }
> ```
>
> There were 2 attacking contracts that transferred DAO tokens to each other. When one attacking contract's transaction finished, balances[msg.sender] = 0 would be correctly set, but the tokens had been transferred to the other contract. Now the other contract performs the attack until it's transaction finishes. The attacking contracts alternate.
>
> [Source](http://hackingdistributed.com/2016/06/18/analysis-of-the-dao-exploit)
>
> @Roland's answer mentions how TheDAO could have prevented this.

Comment: I know, that they had 2 accounts, but 13996/29 ~= 482, and 482 is way to big compared to the depth call stack